# Not able to implement Multiprocessing in python(The parameter is incorrect)

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, multiprocessing

**EDIT**

I am trying to run to functions simultaneously using multiprocessing

```
import serial
import time

from multiprocessing import Process
import sys

sertx = serial.Serial('COM4', 115200)
serrx = serial.Serial('COM3', 115200)

rx_t=0
tx_t=0

def rx(serrx):

    global rx_t

    while True:
        print("hi")
        read_serial=serrx.readline()
        rx_t = time.time()
        print(read_serial)
        print('rx: ',rx_t)

def tx(sertx):
    print("started")
    global tx_t
    while True:

        msg = str(1)
        # print('sending: ',msg.encode())

        msgstat = 'A' + msg
        #print(msgstat)
        #print(type(msgstat))
        tx_t = time.time()
        sertx.write(msg.encode())
        print('tx: ',tx_t)

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    p1 = Process(target=tx,args=(sertx,))
    p2 = Process(target=rx,args=(serrx,))
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```

**Error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/ambuj/Documents/Python Scripts/wave.py", line 58, in <module>
    p1.start()
  File "C:\Users\ambuj\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 112, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "C:\Users\ambuj\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 223, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Users\ambuj\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 322, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Users\ambuj\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 89, in __init__
    reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)
  File "C:\Users\ambuj\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 60, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
ValueError: ctypes objects containing pointers cannot be pickled
PS C:\Users\ambuj\Documents\Python Scripts> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\ambuj\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 99, in spawn_main
    new_handle = reduction.steal_handle(parent_pid, pipe_handle)
  File "C:\Users\ambuj\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 82, in steal_handle
    _winapi.PROCESS_DUP_HANDLE, False, source_pid)
OSError: [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect
```

Basically what I am doing/want to do

I have a transmitter that keeps on transmitting data and I have a receiver that keeps on receiving data. When I transmit the data I note down the time, when I receive the data I note down its time. Scripts are running continuously. I am running these scripts in parallel. As I want to run these scripts simultaneously I am using multiprocessing.

Thanks

Comment: I guess that it is not multiprocessin problem: ```raise SerialException("could not open port {!r}: {!r}".format(self.portstr, ctypes.WinError())) ```

Comment: I am able to open ports individually

Comment: @ArtiomKozyrev I pass the ports variable in the function and got another error.

Comment: No idea what you code is doing but check are you passing the right arguments to the processes? In the function definition you pass serrx to rx, but when defining the process you pass sertx to it instead. Logical error.

Comment: @AmbujeGupta does your code work when you use one com port if you do not use multiprocessing module?

Comment: @Krishi Thanks for pointing out but same error comes after making the changes

Comment: @ArtiomKozyrev Yes it is working individual when I am runing rx or tx in seperate scripts, They are running simultaneously also when I am runing these modules in different script at same time

Comment: @AmbujeGupta I wrote my best suggest, I have no serial ports and can't test it, but it is supposed to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure you do not need to use multiprocessing module for such kind of oeprations, it is used to boost computations. I guess you want reading from one port and writing to another in one process, otherwise you could just write to different programs and run them independenly. For IN/OUT threading module is used.

I've never worked with serial library, but know how to create process whcih listen to input in one thread and print to another thread:

[This is my messenger program](https://github.com/ArtyomKozyrev1989/easy_messenger)

I guess that code can work this way:

```
import serial
import time
from threading import Thread


def rx(_ser_rx):
    while True:
        print("hi")
        read_serial = _ser_rx.readline()
        rx_t = time.time()
        print(read_serial)
        print('rx: ', rx_t)


def tx(_ser_tx):
    print("started")
    while True:
        msg = "1"
        tx_t = time.time()
        _ser_tx.write(msg.encode())
        print('tx: ', tx_t)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ser_tx = serial.Serial('COM4', 115200)
    ser_rx = serial.Serial('COM3', 115200)
    t1 = Thread(target=rx, args=(ser_rx,),)
    t2 = Thread(target=tx, args=(ser_tx,))
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
```

Comment: Thanks man, It worked like charm, I was working on this for more than a day. Thanks a lot.
Can you answer some of my questions?
What was the mistake in my code?
It would help me to increase my understanding .

Comment: @AmbujeGupta multiprocessing module creates separate processes with a separate memory stack, to transfer data from one process to another you need to serialize ("disassemble") it, your serial port object is a difficult staff and another process have no idea what is that and how to assemle it. On the other hand multithreading module is one process = one memory stack,  so any thread can access any object in the stack.